# Is file_get_contents multi line?

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, file

Does file_get_contents maintain line breaks? I thought it did but I have tried this:

```
if($conn){

    $tsql = file_get_contents('scripts/CreateTables/SLR05_MATCH_CREATETABLES.sql');

    $row = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());

}
```

The errors I get is that SQL Server complains that there is incorrect syntax. I get the same errors when I run the SQL Script without any line breaks, which suggests file_get_contents removes them?

When I run the script normally (open the file in SQL Server Management Studio) and execute it, it works perfectly.

So is there something that I can use that maintains line breaks etc? Or is there another problem here in using queries from a file with the SQL Server PHP Driver from Microsoft?

Thanks all for any help

Comment: Try to echo `$tsql` then you will know.

Comment: @Gordon - echo into a browser will not necessarily determine if it contains line breaks. It will appear as a block of text as the browser only makes use of `<br />`, hence the existence of `nl2br`.

Comment: well then, echo it into a shell? Or wrap `<pre>` tags around it? Or look at the page source code in the browser?

Comment: Page source of the browser won't tell you anything either. But the problem has been solved already. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file_get_contents() *does* preserve the file. Perhaps your file contains the wrong "type" of line-breaks? Linux -vs- Windows style?

Also, I'm not familiar with sqlsrv_query() ... can that be used to run multiple queries (as a script might), or only single queries, one at a time?

Comment: You might have a point there, I am not sure if sqlsrv_query() can execute multiple queries. Finding out now...

Comment: No it can not! Thank you for suggesting that, I will have to break up the script into queries or put in an identifier to let me know when a new query starts/end etc.